# How do you read $|a+b| \le |a|+|b|?$

Tags: inequality, terminology, pronunciation

How do you read $|a+b| \le |a|+|b|?$

We have a lesson in mathematical language and sentences. This one is the hardest to answer.

Comment: It is not so hard. How far did you get?

Comment: @eru What's your guess?

Comment: Im still anwsering it but I know now how to read the first set. Im still not sure in the second tho. Im just wanted to make sure my answer is correct.

Comment: Do you mean how to say this out loud? I don't think I've ever had a question like this asked in a math class. Anyway: "The absolute value of a plus b is less than or equal to the absolute value of the sum of a and the absolute value of b" (or you can replace "a plus b" with "the sum of a and b"). Note: There are many possible correct answers.

Comment: What do you mean "how do we read this"?  I'd read it as "the absolute value a plus b is less than or equal to the sum of the absolute value of a plus the absolute value of b".   I don't understand your question or I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: "This one is the hardest to answer."  what were some of the other questions and answers.

Comment: "but I know now how to read the first set"  What sets?  What does "read a set" mean?  What does "read" mean?  I suspect now that your class is developing a specific methodology of interpreting and expressing mathematical concepts and expressions and that you are assume that we being experienced mathematicians will know what it is. But without context we have no idea what you are talking about.  Could you explain?  What would you say the answer to "How do you read: $x +3=5$" is?

Comment: An edit was made since my last comment, an edit that changes the expression and changes what would be a correct way of saying it. The original expression was $|a + b| \; \leq \, |a + |b|\,|.$

Comment: "An edit was made since my last comment"  Wow!  So it was.  I have to wonder why the person who edited it *thought* it was a correction.  There was nor reason to assume that was the meaning. Still, I don't understand the question

Comment: Of course $|a+b| \le |a| + |b|$ is true and $|a+b| \le |a + |b||$ is false (let $a$ and $b$ both be negative for a counter example).  But we don't know that the question being asked was assuming the statement was true.

Answer (score 2):

Break it down...

$|a+b|$ - the absolute value of $a$ plus $b$

$\le$ - is less than or equal to

$|a| + |b|$ - the absolute value of $a$ plus the absolute value of $b$

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value of the sum [of two numbers] does not exceed the sum of the absolute values [of these numbers].